# how to replace a single/double character in a string

Tags: regex, r, string, gsub

I want to replace all the single character in my string with a blank. My idea is that there should be a space before and after the single character. So i have put spaces before and after the character but that doesn't seem to work. I also wanted to replace string with more than 1 char. i.e if i want to replace all char with length 2 or so, then how would the code change.

```
str="I have a cat of white color"
str=gsub("([[:space:]][[a-z]][[:space:]])", "", str)
```

Comment: I believe this would have worked for you: `gsub("[[:space:]][a-z][[:space:]]", " ", str)`. Note that the character class of `[a-z]` has only a single bracket around it.

Comment: @MrFlick: This aint working.

Comment: @MrFlick: Yes With the above string itself. It didnt remove 'a'.

Comment: @MrFlick: Sorry it worked i got confused with some other code. and thanks!

Comment: @MrFlick: why doesnt it work if i have a text string with more than 1 length.

Comment: I don't know what you're trying. it works with `str=c("I have a cat of white color", "I have a dog too")`

Comment: Sorry again, i was focussing on the i. What if the single character is at the start of the sentence. This would do then i guess...str=gsub("^[a-z][[:space:]]", " ", str)

Comment: You can use word boundaries.  Here's one possible solution: `gsub("\\b[A-Za-z]\\s?\\b", "", str)`.

Comment: Lastly i got the idea of the boundary. could you describe about this lookaround that you have used in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the quantifier regex property, e.g. `[a-z]{2}` which matches the letters `a` to `z` twice together.  The regex pattern you want is something along the lines of this:

```
\\s[a-z]{2}\\s
```

You can build this regex dynamically in R using an input number of characters.  Here is a code snippet which demonstrates this:

```
str <- "I have a cat of white color"
nchars <- 2
exp <- paste0("\\s[a-z]{", nchars, "}\\s")

> gsub(exp, "", str)
[1] "I have a catwhite color"
```

Answer (score 2):

> I want to replace all the single character in my string with a blank. My idea is that there should be a space before and after the single character.

The idea is not correct, a word is not always surrounded with spaces. What if the words is at the beginning of the string? Or at the end? Or is followed with a punctuation?

Use **[`\b` word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)**:

> There are *three different positions that qualify as **word boundaries***:
>   
>    - Before the first character in the string, if the first character is a word character.
>    - After the last character in the string, if the last character is a word character.
>    - Between two characters in the string, where one is a word character and the other is not a word character.

**NOTE** that in R, when you use `gsub`, it is best to use it with the PCRE regex (pass `perl=T`):

> POSIX 1003.2 mode of `gsub` and `gregexpr` does not work correctly with repeated word-boundaries (e.g., `pattern = "\b"`). Use `perl = TRUE` for such matches (but that may not work as expected with non-ASCII inputs, as the meaning of ‘word’ is system-dependent).

So, to match all 1-letter words, you need to use

```
gsub("(?i)\\b[a-z]\\b", "REPLACEMENT", input, perl=T) ## To replace 1 ASCII letter words
```

Note that `(?i)` is a case-insensitive modifier (making `a` match both `a` and `A`).

Now, you need to match 2 letter words:

```
gsub("(?i)\\b[a-z]{2}\\b", "REPLACEMENT", input, perl=T) ## To replace 2 ASCII letter words
```

Here, we are using a [**limiting quantifier**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit) `{min, max}` / `{max}` to specify how many times the pattern quantified with this construct can be repeated.

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/x2eHQB):

```
> input = "I am a football fan"
> gsub("(?i)\\b[a-z]\\b", "REPLACEMENT", input, perl=T) ## To replace 1 ASCII letter words
[1] "REPLACEMENT am REPLACEMENT football fan"
gsub("(?i)\\b[a-z]{2}\\b", "REPLACEMENT", input, perl=T) ## To replace 2 ASCII letter words
[1] "I REPLACEMENT a football fan"
```

Comment: Many Thanks i needed a little detailed example and here it is.